# How to add disqus to Ionic app?

Tags: ionic-framework, disqus

I'm new with Ionic framework, and I created simple side-menu app and I want to add disqus comments into it. This is how my code looks like:

I add this srcipt into `<head>` in `index.html`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT BEFORE PASTING INTO YOUR WEBPAGE * * */
var disqus_shortname = '<hooligansapp>'; // Required - Replace '<example>' with your forum shortname

/* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
(function() {
    var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
    dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
})();
```

And this is my template:

```
<ion-view view-title="Comments">
  <ion-content>
      <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

And nothing is happend :(

So, how can I fix it?

Comment: what is logged in the console? can you make a codepen or a plunker?

Comment: Console is empty. Yes, [codepen](http://codepen.io/pavlovdog/pen/MwMYwo)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30291407/disqus-in-ionic-app I would look at this

Answer (score 1):

You have to place the configuration variables and script within the controller of the view.

```
controllers.CollectionsCommentsCtrl = function($scope) {
    var disqus_shortname = 'your_id';
    (function() {
        var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
        dsq.src = '//your_id.disqus.com/embed.js';
        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
    })();
}
```

Here you can see my result:

[image]